# Create/update multiple records using REST (Not Bulk API)

Tags: rest-api

I have used REST in the past for creating/updating single record and used Bulk API to create records in bulk too. But there seems to be new way to creating multiple records using REST. Here is the article - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm

Can someone post few help articles on how to get started? I have not used curl in the past, is there way to test this using PostMaster or WorkBench?

Edit

Let me make it simple. Suppose I have below REST resource in Salesforce, how can I call it to pass multiple contact records?

@RestResource(urlMapping='/insertcontact/*')

global with sharing class Mycontacts{

@HttpPost
  global static List doPost(List lstcnts){
      insert lstcnts;
      return lstcnts;
   }

}

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely use workbench to execute these

Use the below for the request

> /services/data/v34.0/composite/tree/Account

and in the body use the below JSON

```
{
"records" :[{
"attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref1"},
"name" : "SampleAccount1",
"phone" : "1111111111",
"website" : "www.salesforce1.com",
"numberOfEmployees" : "100",
"industry" : "Banking"   
},{
"attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref2"},
"name" : "SampleAccount2",
"phone" : "2222222222",
"website" : "www.salesforce2.com",
"numberOfEmployees" : "250",
"industry" : "Banking"
},{
"attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref3"},
"name" : "SampleAccount3",
"phone" : "3333333333",
"website" : "www.salesforce3.com",
"numberOfEmployees" : "52000",
"industry" : "Banking"
},{
 "attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref4"},
 "name" : "SampleAccount4",
 "phone" : "4444444444",
 "website" : "www.salesforce4.com",
 "numberOfEmployees" : "2500",
 "industry" : "Banking"
  }]
}
```

You should see the response in workbench

Alternatively you can use POSTMAN to experiment with this API .

You will need to create a connected app in salesforce and use oauth 2.0 to get access token for subsequent calls

use the below [link](https://jdspaceit.wordpress.com/2016/09/26/using-postman-for-testing-salesforce-rest-apis/) for reference

Comment: Thanks Mohith for the response. If I run “https://cs3.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/composite/tree/Account” in Postman, I get below error message
 {
    "message": "MediaType of 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is not supported by this resource",
    "errorCode": "UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE"
  }

What should be the “Content-Type” ?

Comment: It was in 2013 at that time we did not have composite or tree API's

Comment: Making some progress. I can insert the account. Couple of follow up questions
- How to differentiate between insert, update, etc
- How can I call custom REST resource?

Comment: Try giving an Id and see what happens .I guess tree is only for inserts .

Comment: Tried that, it complained. I think it is only for inserts. I also tried changing to "Patch" but only Post is supported. 

So back to the question. What is best way to pass json/csv file using REST, preferably custom REST? Seems simple, but only way I see so far is bulk API.

Comment: yes if it is huge csv/json use bulk API .The other option is using apex if the no of records in one context is 1K

Comment: SObject Tree resource only supports create(): https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobject_tree.htm  If you need to do create and update, you can use Batch resource  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_batch.htm or you can issue one-request per update/upsert

Answer (score 2):

As of API v42.2 you can now use the [SObject Collections Composite](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections.htm) endpoints.  There are two major benefits over the existing composite tree & batch endpoints.

1: You can update up to 200 records at a time

2: The updates take place in a single execution context on salesforce.  The other composite record create a context PER RECORD, which make it run incredibly slow for big updates.